# How to show error from UNIQUE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a table where one of the columns (company_nip) has a Unique key to prevent duplication. The problem is, I do not know how to do, to show an error on the page. Here I add them to the database and displays a message that it did well, and how to do that to display a error when the value of company_nip already exists in the database?

```
 if ( isset( $_POST["submit_formm"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && $_POST["company_name"] != "" ){
            $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");
            $company_name = strip_tags($_POST["company_name"], "");
            $wpdb->insert( 
                'test', 
                array( 
                    'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
            );
        }
    echo '<div>Congratz</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $wpdb->insert( 
                'test', 
                array( 
                    'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
            );

if (!$result) {
    //show message that already exist
}
```

Comment: Cheers happy coding.